Derivative and antiderivative of the Bring radical
The Bring radical of a real number $x$ is the unique real number $z=\operatorname{Br}(x)$ such that $z^5+z+x=0$. (Some I've seen say it's actually multivalued, with the real root for a real variable as the principal of five values, but that's not used here).
$$\frac{d}{dx}\operatorname{Br}(x)$$
Note that $\operatorname{Br}^{5}(x)+\operatorname{Br}(x)+x=0$ identically, then differentiate both sides.
$$5\operatorname{Br}^{4}(x)\operatorname{Br}'(x)+\operatorname{Br}'(x)+1=0$$
$$\frac{d}{dx}\operatorname{Br}(x)=\operatorname{Br}'(x)=\frac{-1}{1+5\operatorname{Br}^{4}(x)}$$
This is then used in the second part.
$$\int\operatorname{Br}(x)dx$$
Let $u=\operatorname{Br}(x), du=\frac{-dx}{1+5\operatorname{Br}^{4}(x)}$
This means $dx=-(1+5u^{4})du$ so that we get
$$\int\operatorname{Br}(x)dx=\int -u-5u^{5} du=-\frac{u^{2}}{2} -\frac{5u^{6}}{6}+C=-\frac{\operatorname{Br}^{2}(x)}{2}-\frac{5\operatorname{Br}^{6}(x)}{6}+C$$
Does this seem right? Given that it has an elementary implicit function describing it, it shouldn't be too hard, but I couldn't find anything online doing this so I was doubting myself. Even WolframAlpha didn't seem to know of the Bring radical.
